# Why is the addition of a not equal to whitespace to my if statement result in an error?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

So the problem is asking me to take a string and return a hash mapping each letter to its frequency and to not include whitespaces. My code worked for single words without the second part of my if statement but when i account for the whitespaces it gives me an error

```
def letter_count(str)
  hash_count = {}

  str.split("").each do |char|
    if hash_count[char] == nil && char != " "
      hash_count[char] = 1
    else
      hash_count[char] += 1
    end
  end
  return hash_count
end

:in `block in letter_count': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
            from interview_prep.rb:339:in `each'
            from interview_prep.rb:339:in `letter_count'
            from interview_prep.rb:349:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Read the error again. How does `.. && char != " "` change which branch of code is executed? Why would this different logic result in the effect of `nil += 1` being executed in some cases (and which case / for what values of char)? Follow through the logic and code flow by hand and a piece of a paper if not able to immediately reason the problem.

Comment: Also, consider using a hash with a default value - see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new

Comment: A small point: you are using `if hash_count[char] == nil` to determine if `hash_count` has a key `char`. You should get into the habit of using `hash_count.key?(char)` (aka `has_key?`) for that. One day you may have a hash with a key equal to `nil` (intentionally), but forget that when you are checking for the presence of some other key.

Comment: `str.chars.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)`

Answer (score 1):

you should change,

```
if hash_count[char] == nil && char != " "
```

to

```
if hash_count[char] == nil || char != " "
                          ^^^^^
```

to omit syntax error, however your function will not work as you expect.

however if you want a better solution for this problem look this one liner

```
your_string.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '').chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|k, h| h[k] += 1 }
```